# How to write an efficient LINQ query when searching by both parent and child entity fields

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am having a problem with understanding how to best write a linq query in C# to solve the following problem:

I have two models, lets call them **Item** and **Person**. **Person** can have multiple **Items**, so there is a reference to **Person** object in every **Item** object. In my query I want to find all **Persons** that match certain criteria (eg. their gender is male) but they also have to have **Items** that match other criteria (eg. they have items that are named "Car").

The person before me tackled this issue by selecting Items and grouping them by their persons. So the query was something like:

`var result = Items.FilterBy(x => x.Person.Gender == "Male" && x.Name == "Car").GroupBy(x => x.Person).ToList().Select(g => g.Key);`

I was thinking that .ToList() was to blame for the poor performance but I am unable to get the query to work without it. However there is also something scratching the back of my mind and telling me that this was not the best approach possible, since filtering is usually done (in 90% of the cases) only for **Persons**. So I am thinking a better way would be to select only Persons that match the criteria and then do the checking of their **Items** (if required). Is it possible to write a linq that would solve that?

One solution would be to check if filtering needs to be done for items in the first place and then perform the suitable query so for example:

```
if(shouldFilterItems)
{
    result = Items.FilterBy(x => x.Person.Gender == "Male" && x.Name == "Car").GroupBy(x => x.Person).ToList().Select(g => g.Key);
}
else
{
    result = Persons.FilterBy(x => x.Gender == "Male");
}
```

However I would like to avoid such solution if possible and have everything in one query. Is it possible to write such query and would it have better performance than the initial group by?

Answer (score 0):

As it happens with LINQ-to-objects, the execution order takes a big toll at a statement like this, as it cannot be optimized automatically, unlike EF and SQL execution plans.

One possible optimization for you would be running the Group By statement against a property instead of an object, and another one would be to only take the first Person out of the group to comlpete the list.

```
var result = items.Where(x=> x.Name=="Car" && x.person.Gender=="Male").GroupBy(x => x.person.UID).Select(x => x.First().Key).ToList();
```

Where a Person's UID is an unique identifier of such a Person.

I have a simple fiddle set up https://dotnetfiddle.net/VBGp4l where you can see (totaly not accurate) execution times. They would totally depend on your data and objects.

Another optimization I'd like to recommend is to move all this data management into an actual database and access it via EF or a procedure.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your input. I tried running my query as: items.Where(x=> x.Name=="Car" && x.person.Gender=="Male").GroupBy(x => x.Person.Id).Select(x => x.First().Person) but I keep getting the following exception InnerException = {"Column 'Person.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."}. However this seems to be NHibernate exception not a LINQ related one.

Comment: One drawback of this method is that you can't actually get the parent object after the GroupBy clause, you need to either expand the GroupBy to contain all the fields you need to use further (SQL-like), or use the Id list to select Persons back from the list of all Persons via Intersect. Keep in mind the performance drawbacks, sometimes it will still be faster to GroupBy whole objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have a true one-to-many relation between Persons and Items: Every Person has zero or more Items, every Item belongs to exactly one Person.

If you follow the entity framework guidelines for one-to-many relations, you'll have something similar to the following:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every person has zero or more items:
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}

    public Gender Gender {get; set;}
    ... // other properties
}

class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Item belongs to exactly one Person using foreign key
    public int PersodId {get; set;}
    public virtual Person Person {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties
}
```

If you follow the [entity framework code-first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) then this is all entity framework needs to know to understand that you designed a one-to-many. If you want to use different column names, or table names, you'll need the use of attributes or fluent API.

> I want to find all Persons that match certain criteria (eg. their
>   gender is male) but they also have to have Items that match other
>   criteria (eg. they have items that are named "Car").

Once you've defined your one-to-many correctly, then the query is simple:

```
var CarOwningMales = myDbContext.Persons
    .Where(person => person.Gender == Gender.Male
        && person.Items.Where(item => item.Name == "Car").Any())
    .Select(person => new
    {   
        // TODO: select the properties you plan to use 
    });
```

In words: from the collection of persons, take only those persons that have a Gender that equals Gender.Male, and that have at least one Item with a Name that equals "Car". From these selected persons, transfer only the selected properties to the local process.

If you want all males with all their cars, I'd go for the following:

```
var malesWithTheirCars = myDbContext.Persons
    .Where(person = person.Gender == Gender.Male)
    .Select(person => new
    {
        Name = person.Name,
        ...
        Cars = person.Items.Where(item.Name == "Car").ToList(),
    });
```

Note that this will also select males without Cars. If you want to omit those, add:

```
    .Where(person => person.Cars.Any());
```